# Having memory managment issue with file

Tags: c++, memory-management, file-handling

I'm opening file in 1 function and trying to use pointer of that in other function. But i dunno why its not working.
Below is the Code.

```
void ReadFile()
    {
        float data;
        int total_rows, pairs;
        double longitude, latitude;

        {
            GsmFingreprintEuc *g;
            ll.push_front(new GsmFingreprintEuc);

            if(file_ptr.is_open())
                cout<<"Yes!!"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"NO!!"<<endl;
            file_ptr >> data;
            total_rows = data;
            cout<<"Total Rows:"<<total_rows<<endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++)
            {
                g = ll.front();
                file_ptr >> data;
                pairs = data;
                for (int j = 0; j < pairs; j++)
                {
                    int id;
                    double value;
                    file_ptr >> data;
                    id = data;
                    file_ptr >> data;
                    value = data;
                    g->add_map(id, value);

                }
                file_ptr >> data;
                latitude = data;
                g->set_latitude(latitude);
                file_ptr >> data;
                longitude = data;
                g->set_longitude(longitude);

            }

        }

        cout<<"Size: "<<ll.size()<<endl;

    }

    DtFileReaderEuc(string file_path)
    {
        cout << "I am in Constructor" << endl;
        cout << file_path << endl;
        fstream file_ptr(file_path.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
        if (file_ptr.is_open()) {
            cout << "Yahhy!! file Opend successfully" << endl;

            float data;
            file_ptr >> data;
            double total_rows = data;
            cout<<"Total Rows:"<<total_rows<<endl;


            //file_ptr = myfile;
            ReadFile();
            //myfile.close();

        } else
            cout << "Wohoo!! Wrong path" << endl;

        cout << "Done!!" << endl;

    }

};
```

and when i rund this code output is:
"I am in Constructor
/home/umar/Desktop/DataFile/dha_dataset.gfp
Yahhy!! file Opend successfully
Total Rows:7257
NO!!
Total Rows:0
Size: 1
Done!!"

Thanks in advance

Comment: This shouldn't even compile! `file_ptr` (which isn't a pointer by the way) is local to `DtFileReaderEuc`, and cannot be used anywhere else. You could pass it as an argument to `ReadFile`.

Comment: @BoBTFish but Its Compiling. is there anyway else to do this without passing it as an argument?

Comment: Ok, I can't even start to turn this into something I can compile. Too much of the real code is missing. Please create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org). Also, read [this](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191).

Comment: At a guess (and nvoigt has already said more or less the same), you have another `file_ptr` somewhere, which is what `ReadFile` sees. You create a local `file_ptr` in `DtFileReaderEuc`, which [*hides*](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/name_hiding.htm) the other one. You could have a member variable (I recommend some naming convention for member variables so you don't make this sort of error. A lot of people use an `_` at the end of the name), or pass the `fstream` by reference into `ReadFile`, if it doesn't need to be kept around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fstream file_ptr(file_path.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
```

This is a new fstream variable local to your constructor. You probably meant to use the private variable of the same name.

Comment: well want to open file in constructor and want to use that file_ptr in ReadFile() function can you help me with that how to do that ?
Thank You.

Comment: @OOkhan Consider having a member `std::ifstream file_`, then open it in the initialiser list: `MyClass(std::string const & filename) : file_(filename) { if (!file_) std::cerr << "Uh oh!\n" }`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, in order to make the code compile you have put a `fstream file_ptr` somewhere you could see it from `ReadFile` but you forgot to remove the local copy in `DtFileReaderEuc`. 
In this case you use the local version in `DtFileReaderEuc` and the "global" one in the `ReadFile` which is not opened.
As someone already suggested to you, try pass `file_ptr` to `ReadFile`

Comment: well I'm opening file in constructor so cant return. is there anyway else?

Answer (score 0):

The `file_ptr` scope is not clear. You have declared and defined the `file_ptr` in `DtFileReaderEuc` so you have to pass its pointer to inner function `ReadFile`, otherwise, declaration of `file_ptr` should be in outer scope and put the definition in `DtFileReaderEuc`.

Answer (score -1):

create file_ptr a class member and initialize the same in ctor, then it can be used anywhere in the member functions.

To get the file pointer outside class use getter/setter functions.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment. (And actually, I have already made the same comment, so please do not add to the noise).